# Как перезаписать значение ячеек в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть старый курс рубля и новый курс, старая маржа и новая маржа.
Цены хранятся в ячейке price(integer) рублях.

Необходимо после изменения курса рубля или процента маржи перезаписывать цену всех товаров. Т.е. сначала отнять старую маржу, разделить на курс рубля, а затем умножить на новый курс и добавить новую маржу.

$oldProfit, $newProfit - integer

$oldCourse, $newCourse - float

Текущий вариант кода после перезаписи уменьшает цену. Как понимаю из-за обрезания остатка, но возможно и формула кривая.

```
((((price - (price * '.$oldProfit.' / 100)) / '.$oldCourse.')  * '.$newCourse.') + 
((((price - (price * '.$oldProfit.' / 100)) / '.$oldCourse.')  * '.$newCourse.') * '.$newProfit.' / 100))
```

Как решить эту задачу? Прощу помощи. Вариант хранить данные по другому не предлагать - слишком большие затраты.

Comment: надо бы хранить базовую цену товаров в отдельной колонке. И тогда просто пересчитывать при смене курса или маржена... У Вас есть такие права/желание?

Comment: если в структуре базы данных ничего менять нельзя, то что же тут можно «решить»? какую-то другую «особо волшебную» формулу придумать?

Comment: Решил задачу добавлением отдельной колонки.